# modifying url when using script manager history property

Tags: asp.net, ajax, history

i think this type of questions already asked before and the solutions suggest that you should use `Windows.location.hash`
but i dont know at what instance of program i have to do this while adding the history point or in the navigate event of script manager(i mean calling javascript function from code behind)
Some people suggest that we have to modify the MicrosoftAjax.js file can you please suggest me something

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to invent a wheel and to use already available programs, for example Webdav.

Client: http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajaxfilebrowser/